# ANCOVA with random effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, ancova

I have searched on how to perform a ANCOVA with random effects, but have had no luck finding anything that definitively tells me if that is allowed, and if it is allowed how to do it?

Are ANCOVAs with random effects the same as a linear mixed model? Am I better off just running a linear mixed model vs a ANCOVA in this case?

Comment: ANCOVA is linear regression with a categorical variable predictor and a continuous variable as a covariate (also a predictor but not the predictor being tested). If you want to include a random effect, then feel free to do so. Whether you call it ANCOVA with a random effect or a linear mixed model, you’re doing the same procedure. Depending on the software you use, you might have an easier time coding it one way (probably the explicit regression, but maybe not).